# NSTabViewController subclass doesn't seem to work with IBInspectable

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstabviewcontroller

Does IBInspectable work with subclasses of NSTabViewController? The properties seem to show up in Interface Builder (and can be set), but, are nil when running my app. Basic code that I have is

```
class XYViewController : NSTabViewController {

@IBInspectable var barColor: NSColor?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   Swift.print("\(barColor)") //Prints nil here
}
```

If I have the XYViewController inherit from NSViewController instead, the property set in IB is assigned correctly. Is there anything else I need to do, to get the IBInspectable working with a NSTabViewController? I am using XCode 7.0.1 on Yosemite 10.10.5. Thanks

Regards

George

Comment: Can you check if identity inspector -> user defined runtime attributes are set when you change color?

Comment: The user defined runtime attributes seem to be set correctly

Comment: Try to add awakeFromNib + breakpoint there to check how many times it's called. Also reconnect barColor (weird Xcode bug)

Comment: awakeFromNib is called only once (program breaks only once at the function while debugging). The barColor is nil at that point. Thanks

Comment: same issue. To me it's a bug

Comment: @MarekH Thanks for checking.